# Unit test case is failing in my React app because of some issue in fabric

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I am new to react and also wanted to use office react ui for one of our requirement i followed the git hub and able to use office ui react components in my components but while running my first test case for App.js it is giving me below error.

> E:\net_react\my-new-app\ClientApp\node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\Fabric.js:1
>   ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './components/Fabric/index';
>                                                                                            ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
>
> at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
>     at Object. (src/components/Login.js:13:592)
>     at Object. (src/components/Home.js:2:14)

And i have an import statement  in my Login.js

```
import { Fabric } from '../../node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Fabric';
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is because your test harness does not support ES 6 modules (which is what is in lib in Fabric 6).

Try importing instead from `office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/Fabric` or `office-ui-fabric-react` (which has bundle size implications unless you're able to utilize Tree Shaking) or modify your test harness's module map to redirect `lib/` imports into `lib-commonjs`.

**Update**

To elaborate on the answer above, the [Fabric release notes](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Fabric-6-Release-Notes) has guidance for Jest configuration:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/(.*)$": "office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/$1"
}
```

Comment: Tried this "office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/Fabric" and its working and could you please let me know how i can do this in my jest configuration. 
"modify your test harness's module map to redirect lib/ imports into lib-commonjs"

Comment: @cliff Koh I wish I could upvote this more than once.  Hours of my life banging my head against the wall with the jest and ts config

Comment: @Nagaraju sorry this came really late but I have updated the answer above with a configuration for Jest.